# Leaflet : write attributes of a geojson into a field of a form

Tags: javascript, forms, leaflet

I work on leaflet and I have a geojson composed of points with attributes (id1, id2, id3 ...).

I want that when a user click on a point, a form is open in a fancybox.
In the sametime the attribute id1 is saved. Then the attribute id1 goes to the field "id1" of my form opened in the fancybox.

I managed to do it with the latitude and longitude attributes (layer.getLatLng().lat and layer.getLatLng().lng). But I really don't know how it works with a "standatd" attribute.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The feature of each layer in your GeoJSON layer is stored as property `feature` in the layer itself:

```
var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON({
   "type": "Feature",
   "id": 1,
   "properties": {
       "name": "Foo"
   },
   "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates": [0,0]
   }
});

geojsonLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    console.log(layer.feature.id) // logs '1' to console
    console.log(layer.feature.properties.name) // logs 'Foo' to console
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how is it possible to put that feature.id in a form (by using GET method for example) ? That form would be openned by a click on each point of the geojson. Thanks !